# The eval( ) function stops the program when i enter a large expression with a square of a number. Python

Tags: python

I have a calculator for my friends. When someone enters an expression like `eval(99999999999999999**9999999999999999)` my program stops working. How do I fix this if possible? If not, can I just disallow it to be entered and how?

Comment: Any programming language will crash on that, the number is incommensurately too big,  this is just impossible.

Comment: It hangs because that's a massively large number that takes a very long time to compute.

Comment: The easiest would be to tell your friends not to do that. :)

Comment: You could do what most calculators do and just print ERR or something similar if the input provided is way too large.

Comment: You should implement some kind of "infinity"-type in your calculator to handle calculations like these

Comment: do something like `if input > bignumber: raise error`

Comment: You could use "multiprocessing" to create a child process which executes the calculation and can be killed if it needs too much time.

Comment: That's not a square of the number. `99999999999999999 ** 2` would be a square. And please be exceedingly careful with `eval()`. It is very dangerous to use on untrusted input.

Comment: This "program stops working" is a minor problem. If you use `eval` someone could even wipe your hard disk. Read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) (over 9 years old and still valid).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I fix this if possible?

**You can't.** 99999999999999999 to the power of 9999999999999999 is way too big to be computed.

> If not, can I just disallow it to be entered and how?

You can set certain constraints on the `input` by putting it into a `while` loop:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number smaller than 100"))
while number > 100:
    number = int(input("Enter a number smaller than 100"))
```